# Microphone is not working after new RAM is inserted

Tags: 16.04, sound, microphone

I have just added the second Kingston memory stick to my computer. After connecting everything,I had arranged a chat with my client but my headset microphone is not working. I have tried to change all the slots but to no avail: 
[image]

I have tried everything, including using alsamixer:
[image]

Every time I reboot my comp second column,headphone goes to 0!
[image]

My cards
[image]

What should I try next?

Answer (score 4):

If removing the RAM stick that you just installed fixes it, then that could mean the RAM is bad and you'd have to run memtest86+ http://memtest.org/ or something like that to verify. (This is unlikely, but possible)

If it's still not working after removing the second RAM stick, then you may want to test the microphone on other PCs with the same and different Operating Systems if possible to make sure the mic didn't just happen to die right when you installed your new RAM. (Also unlikely, but also possible)

Hope one of these helps with your issue.

Comment: Take a look at my edit!

Comment: This could still very well be a RAM issue and I would still encourage you to at least test that if nothing else, something about this screams that this is a hardware issue to me. Where (on case header, in the motherboard, on a sound card) and how (USB, Aux cord?) are the headphone and microphone plugged in?

Comment: Also, you said when you chat with a client it doesn't work, what application are you using and do other applications properly pick up your microphone? Does that input level sensor in the ubuntu sound settings move when you speak into it? Is your headset wireless and needs to be powered on?

Comment: Skype application.

Comment: Please answer all the other questions I have listed above, they could all potentially be relevant.

Comment: Headset has wire(red and green end).I have plugged it behind on my Desktop(three colors).I have tried to change all the jacks,still it does not work.By the way I have tested memory works fine.

Comment: If possible, can you plug another microphone into the red/pink jack (should be where your microphone part is plugged into and see if another microphone is recognized? Or, do you have another computer you can test your headset on?

Comment: Unfortunately not,my laptop is not working. I do not have another microphone.

Comment: Have you confirmed if you mic works in other applications or not? That would be helpful, also, you said you changed all the jacks in a previous comment, only keep the microphone jack in the mic jack in the back and the headphone jack in the headphone jack in back (on most basic motherboards, mic is red/pink, headphone is green).